# Getting TabSpec id from activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I'm using a tabhost in my Android application that contains 4 tabs. I'm navigating to the same activity from all these 4 tabs. So I need to distinguish between those 4 tabs.

How to get the tag (specified while creating tabspec) from the called activity?